# how do i multiply use input numbers with numbers i put in

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I multiply user input numbers with numbers I type in?

I have

```
weight = input ('What is your weight')
print ('this is your weight on the moon')
print weight*.165
```

this does not work why?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems. As noted by Outlaw Lemur, print is a function in Python 3. Also, you'll need to make the weight either a float or an int (it doesn't matter which) or else you'll get a TypeError.

```
weight = float(input ('What is your weight'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, the [`print` statement has been replaced by the `print()` function](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html). You need:

```
weight = input ('What is your weight')
print ('this is your weight on the moon')
print (weight*.165)
```